# The Necessity of Descriptors for RestfulAPI

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, descriptor

I was searching the Restful API versions, and I finally know the basic differences between v1 and v2.
v1 supports only XML descriptors while v2 supports JSON descriptors.
Then, I researched descriptors and I realised that they look like UML Class Diagrams.
But I didn't understand this: 
Do we have to use descriptors for Restful API or why we should use that?